# Show popup kind of cell renderer

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I want to show a popup kind of cell renderer when a cell is focused. For suppose, if the row height is 50px, when a specific cell is focused, I want to have a custom cell renderer that has a height greater than 50px(e.g., 80px). I have developed a custom cell renderer, but only the content which fits within the cell height(50px) is visible and the remaining content is cut off. I tried setting up absolute positioning,higher z-index etc., but nothing worked. For cell editors, we can specify `isPopup(){ return true }`. Is it possible to have the same thing for cell renderer as well?

Comment: ever figure out an answer? I am in the same situation, trying to get a (CSS+JS+HTML workaround) multi-select dropdown with checkboxes shown. I got it to work as an editor, but the default renderer doesn't have a down arrow, and requires a double-click to show the editor, which then the user has to provide a 3rd click to open the drop-down.

Comment: Even I am looking for solution for the same problem. +1'd if SOF algorithm can prioritize the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible to create a renderer that displays outside of the cell.
There is no API that I'm aware of to do it. Perhaps someone can come up with some sort of "hack", but just short of that, no.